# Post onto multiple facebook pages

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new to facebook api, for last two days I'm looking to find a way to post onto multiple facebook pages.

I've list of facebook page id's e.g.: `1234, 34456, 77889,44224432`. I don't own those pages. Is there a way I could post same message on all of these pages once?

Comment: this sounds like spam. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm working on an app which integrates with facebook pages. One of the senario is to post message on to the page via app and in our case there are many common messages with little customization that need to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to authenticate onto the pages and use

`https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed`

as your action using cURL.

**Reference**: http://php-academy.blogspot.ca/2011/04/how-to-post-from-facebook-app-to.html